# Why does the function return two different values even when nothing is changed in the function call?

Tags: c++11

In the first case the code returns -1

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
int compare( const T &val1, const T &val2){

    if(val1 < val2) return -1;
    if(val2 < val1) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(){

    std::string v1= "hello", v2 = "world";
    std::cout << compare("hello", "world") << std::endl;
}
```

In the second case the code returns 1 even when there is no change in the method call.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
int compare( const T &val1, const T &val2){

    if(val1 < val2) return -1;
    if(val2 < val1) return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(){

    std::cout << compare("hello", "world") << std::endl;
}
```

I am using g++ 7.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using operarors like `<` on pointers that do not point to elements of the sane array is undefined behaviour. Different string literals are different arrays, and decay to pointers to elements of different arrays. Any result is possible. Either program may print 0, or crash, or launch a nuclear warhead, or do one of these things today and another one tomorrow. And of course two programs with UB that differ in seemingly irrelevant details (like v1, v2 inyour case) may also behave differently. None of it is predictable.

Comment: v1 and v2 are not being used in both the cases, so why is the type T not getting deduced to string instead of char*

Comment: Why do you expect it to be deduced to anything other than const char*?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases `T` is deduced to be `char [6]`. While comparing array decays to pointer to first element of array - `char*`. So you are comparing two pointers, and the result is unpredictable because you don't know how these string literals - "hello" and "world" are located into memory - which has lower address.

You get 0 (what should be impossible because *hello* and *world* as string literals cannot occupy the same memory) because these conditions

```
if(val1 < val2) return -1;
if(val2 > val1) return 1;    // condition val1 > val2 was not tested
// return 0
```

are the same. 
Should be:

```
if(val1 < val2) return -1;
if(val1 > val2) return 1;
```

Visit [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/uZzAjw) and see what code is generated when the line

```
std::string v1= "hello", v2 = "world";
```

is commented.

[1] when uncommented the code is:

```
.LC0:
        .string "hello"
.LC1:
        .string "world"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    rbx
```

[2] when commented

```
.LC0:
        .string "world"
.LC1:
        .string "hello"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, OFFSET
```

Do you see it now? `LC0` and `LC1` are labels memory (some values which are compared), that is why output is unpredictable, it depends how compiler stores string literals in memory, which is first.

Comment: But in both of the cases the input to the function is same, that is, I am using constant values to pass into the functions. and not the string variables.

Comment: @AmanVaishya Not, input variables are not the same, in first case they are strings, instance of std::string. In second case they are string literals - byte sequence in read-only memory, then pointers are compared. Also your conditions are wrong, I fixed my answer.

Comment: I have changed the condition

Comment: You should not edit question, when an answer was given. Changed condition changes nothing. Still the output for comparing string literals is unpredictable. Output depends how string literals are stored into memory, which has lower address. While comparing two `char [6]` their first byte addresses are taken.

Comment: I have changed the condition, it was a small typo. Also just changing the condition doesn't solve my problem either.

Comment: what I want to know is, how is 
std::cout << compare("hello", "world")

in the first case is deduced to string while in the second case it is being deduced to char*. If you could give some references, that would be helpful

Comment: @AmanVaishya Ugh, my fault, I edited my answer with link to godbolt for testing.

Comment: @AmanVaishya Why do you think it's deducing to different types? What's changing is where the `char*` literals are stored in memory.